# When I type flutter doctor it doesn't work

Tags: flutter, console

when we type flutter doctor it gets stuck here

When we write flutter doctor, what is the reason it gets stuck like this?

> Flutter doctor fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this: 'git  [...] -- [...]

Comment: Seems like a git problem. Just reinstall flutter.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25056